# vim script about cscope can't be execute

Tags: vim, cscope

Here is my code

```
let $CSCOPE_DB = "/home/simon/cscope"
if has("cscope")
set csprg=/usr/local/bin/cscope
set csto=0
set cst
set nocsverb
" add any database in current directory
if filereadable("cscope.out")
    cs add cscope.out
" else add database pointed to by environment
elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
    cs add $CSCOPE_DB."/".expand('%:h')."/cscope.out"
endif
set csverb
endif
```

i define my cscope files collector $CSCOPE_DB, and i wanna vi or gvim auto load the cscope.out file when i open one of the project files, but that doesn't work.

i create a foldor for each project under $CSCOPE_DB, and the folder's name is the same as project

Comment: Isn't `$CSCOPE_DB` supposed to point to a file?

Comment: I make it point to a folder where I put all cscope.* files of projects @romainl

Comment: Have you fixed it? It's been a long time since you posted it. If not, have you tried to remove the space between $CSCOPE_DB and '=' , and make sure there is no intervening space between '=' and path_to_some , too.